# KML layers disappear on small zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-styling

I've got a problem with KML Layers. All the layers that are plotted on the map look good on initial zoom level. If you change zoom level to lower one you'll see that some borders and white areas dissapear. If you magnify the map to the initial zoom level again - it works.
Strange.

Could you take a look? Here is the example for USA: http://tinyurl.com/kmlproplem.
On zoom level 3 (default one) you will see the two parts of USA filled with white color. On lower zoom level only one part of it is visible + some borders dissapear.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see what you're describing at all. I see a dark/light green world map with no white borders or areas. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here you can find what I initially see: http://i55.tinypic.com/333bz47.png

Comment: This is what I see: i52.tinypic.com/se8386.png - not the same, and some text output

Comment: Ok, now I see the same as you posted, and can verify the error.

Comment: Ok. That'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've resolved the issue. The problem was too detailed KMLs. I used simplified version for small zoom levels and more detailed one for greater zoom levels.